# Support vector machines in target motion analysis: relevant to CS theory?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We have a question on Physics, [Target motion analysis (TMA), zig-zag navy maneuvers & Suport vector machines (SVM)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16959/target-motion-analysis-tma-zig-zag-navy-maneuvers-suport-vector-machines-s), which is off topic there, but a couple people have suggested it might fit here. It doesn't seem very CS-theoretical to me, but since I'm not familiar with this topic I thought I'd ask: would this question be appropriate for migration to CS Theory?

Comment: not an expert, but I think [stats.se] might be more suitable.

Comment: @Kaveh: Doesn't Lev Reyzin do this kind of stuff?  It seems like a machine learning problem.  Not saying it is on topic here, but there might be users who can give pointers to the literature.

Comment: I have already said I am not an expert.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... we wound up sending it to stats.SE. Feel free to close or delete this question if you want.

Comment: Thanks for asking though !!